# HTML - font color determined by value

Tags: html, css, colors

How can one set a font color to be determined by the value of the text enclosed using HTML and/or CSS. The enclosed text is constrained to integer values.
The desired effect is similar to a [heat map](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=opera&sa=N&tbo=d&channel=suggest&tbm=isch&tbnid=zMw4S613rh327M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24253-customizable-heat-maps&docid=gRID8AzccpX9qM&imgurl=http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/24253/2/heatmap.png&w=839&h=506&ei=nQ-zUNeMH42C9QS_2IGoBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=198&vpy=182&dur=1058&hovh=174&hovw=289&tx=176&ty=97&sig=115260270143155142479&page=1&tbnh=126&tbnw=217&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:118&biw=1280&bih=669).

A possible solution might look like this:

```
<FONT COLOR=function> 1 </FONT>
<FONT COLOR=function> 100 </FONT>
```

where "function" would resolve to:

```
<FONT COLOR="red"> 1 </FONT>
<FONT COLOR="green"> 100 </FONT>
```

Comment: As far as I know, by using solely HTML and/or CSS you can't do that. But using JavaScript (jQuery) it could surely be done. Or, if you can, you can use the server language (like PHP for example) and prepare the output before actually outputing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery something like the following may suit your needs (based on what I think it is you tried to explain):

```
$('font').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var colorVal;
    // determine your color
    $(this).attr('color', colorVal);
});
```

But I would recommend using classes or style manipulation as the HTML you are proposing to use has been deprecated.